# Wicket SAML SSO redirect from mounted page?

Tags: redirect, wicket, saml

I want to use Web SSO SAML in my Wicket application. I thought it would be a good idea to mount a `Page` and try to use `OpenSAML` in that.

I tried to use  OpenSAML's `HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder` directly on the `HttpServletReponse` like this:

```
    WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse) this.getRequestCycle().getResponse();
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) webResponse.getContainerResponse();
```

Then I use the decoder on that, which builds a redirect and commits the response.

But of course, this gives errors as I mis-use the Wicket-way do doing thing.

```
2016-09-23 13:13:16,236 ERROR - ListenerCollection         - Error invoking listener: org.apache.wicket.Application$3@4c8f505b
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response is committed
```

What would be the proper way to do a redirect in such a way that I can access Wicket's session etc? Because I want to prevent this redirect if I know some attribute of the user, which might already have a `WicketSession`?

Comment: Where do you do the redirect ? It looks like you try to do it at the end of the request cycle where the response is already committed. Is it an option to do it in IRequestCycleListener ?

Comment: I currently do it in the constructor of the `Page`. I know there is a `RedirectException` but that does not give enough control.  How would I do it in `IRequestCycleListener`? I have never meddled this far in the Wicket internals

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly you actually do. Just unwrapping the container response should not lead to such error. What do you do with it in the page constructor ?

Comment: Well, I don't really need to do it in a `Page` constructor, but I could not find a better way yet. I would like, based on a value in the `WicketSession` to directly redirect to an external url and I need to be able to add headers to the `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: It is still unclear why it fails with this error in the page constructor. But I'd recommend you to try with IRequestCycleListener#onBeginRequest() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving  it like this:

```
public SSOSamlPage(final PageParameters pp) {
    final WebResponse webResponse = (WebResponse) this.getRequestCycle().getResponse();
    final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) webResponse.getContainerResponse();

     final IModel<String> urlModel = Model.of("");
    final HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder encoder = new HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder() {
        @Override
        protected void doEncode() throws MessageEncodingException {
            final MessageContext<SAMLObject> messageContext = this.getMessageContext();

            LOG.info("setRelayState for PP: {}", pp);

            SAMLBindingSupport.setRelayState(messageContext, PageParameterUtils.toBase64(pp));

            final SAMLObject outboundMessage = messageContext.getMessage();

            final String endpointURL = this.getEndpointURL(messageContext).toString();

            this.removeSignature(outboundMessage);

            final String encodedMessage = this.deflateAndBase64Encode(outboundMessage);

            final String redirectURL = this.buildRedirectURL(messageContext, endpointURL, encodedMessage);
            urlModel.setObject(redirectURL);
        }

    };
 ....
 throw new RedirectToUrlException(urlModel.getObject());
```